# Logic - What does ∴ mean in a truth table?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I see the symbol used, and I've never seen it logically defined. In words, It's defined as a symbol meaning 'therefore'. Because of a lack of definition, I have no idea why this is false:

```
A
B
∴C
```

For me, this statemnet could mean one of two things.

1. 'If A and B thus C':
   (A^B) -> C
   i.e same as conditional
2. That ∴ is the same as the conditional, only without a truth value for when the premises is false (conclusions cannot draw upon a false premise) 
   'A thus B', perhaps? I've read that a valid argument is only so if it is (logically/symbolically/algebraically) impossible that the conclusion be false, given that premise is true.

I am not certain on that, and any correction would be appreciated. However, regardless, I still can't find a strict, logical definition or equivalent of ∴, and it's not that I haven't looked, the ∴ only ever seems to be talked about, never strictly defined.

Comment: Basically, 1. It just means "therefore" :)

Comment: Oh ok Sweet. :)

Comment: In older books you may see the upside-down version of that symbol, meaning "since" or "because".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol means "therefore".  In common usage, "therefore" is a stronger statement than "if/then".  When we say "$p$ therefore $q$", we mean *both* "if $p$ then $q$" *and* "$p$ is true".  Thus we assure that $q$ is true, which the "if/then" statement alone does not.  Mathematically:

$p \therefore q \equiv ((p\rightarrow q) \land p)$

Comment: The proposition $(p\to q)\wedge p$ is logically equivalent to $p\wedge q$.  This solution overlooks the semantic meaning of "therefore".

Comment: Ahh, so it's not just a confusing term, with no symbolic meaning. Though I do see why the therefore and and symbols, even though logically the same, would differ, as the former represents a step in an premise, where the latter represents the entire premise and concluding point :)

Comment: Or you could say that "$p$ and $q$ is true" is a corrollary if you prove both "if $p$ then $q$" and "$p$ is true".

Answer (score 1):

It is a semantic statement rather than a syntactic one.  Syntax is the level of propositional calculus in which $A,B, A\wedge B$ live.  Semantics is at a higher level, where we assign truth values to propositions based on interpreting them in a larger universe.

Your (1),  $(A\wedge B) \to C$, is a proposition.  It may be true or false.  However $(A\wedge B) \therefore C$ cannot be false.  It can be a valid proof, or invalid, which is again at a a semantic level rather than a syntactic one.

For example, if $P$ holds then $\neg(\neg P)$ must hold.  We have $P \therefore \neg(\neg P)$.  This is a different meaning than $P\to \neg(\neg P)$, which is a proposition that happens to be always true (a tautology).  Asserting that $P\to \neg(\neg P)$ is logically equivalent to a tautology, is equivalent to $P \therefore \neg(\neg P)$.

Comment: But there must be a way for us to know if it's valid or invalid, the whole point of logic, surely, is to eliminate interpretation.

Comment: To test if a proof is valid we must exit propositional calculus.  For example, using a truth table.  In practice, we prove certain theorems semantically using truth tables (like modus ponens), and then use them to prove other things.

Comment: @user108262: You remember http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820? Just look up the rules for Fitch-style natural deduction.. there are only a small number, one introduction rule and one elimination rule for each connective, and then add the rules I gave you for quantifiers and you're done. Any argument that cannot be proven via those rules is invalid. Simple as that.

Comment: @Though I must say that this fact that those rules are **sufficient** is by no means trivial. It's known as the completeness theorem for first-order logic, and requires a strong enough **meta-system** to prove this fact.