# What type of logical statement is this statement and how do you prove it?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I'm learning proof techniques. I understand "if, then" statements and how they correspond to "if p, then q" and "hypothesis, and conclusion". But, I don't understand what kind of statement the following is considered to be:

"The sum of two even integers is always even"

How do I look at this statement logically, using p and q? Is there a hypothesis and conclusion here? Is this considered a non-conditional statement? And lastly, how I do I prove such a statement?

This was one of the first statements I came across when I started learning how to do proofs, so I have seen the proof for it. I just don't understand it logically.

Thank you for the help.

UPDATE:

Bram28 asked, "Do you have to use formal logic for this? Or would a mathematical proof suffice?"

What would formal logic look like for this proof? Or, am I misunderstanding something?

I've been reading more about ZFC Theory and http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/opoeALTV.html for instance. And, I can see how these proofs are being constructed.

That's why I am so curious as to how Bram28's idea of formal logic would apply to my original post.

Comment: Perhaps you would prefer to write something like "if $m,n$ are both even integers then $m+n$ is also even."  The proof, of course, is "$m=2M\, \text{and} \,n=2N\implies m+n=2(M+N)$".

Comment: Is that acceptable and expected when coming across a statement like this? I did read how you can re-write statements in such a fashion. It just confused me that this wasn't explained in any of the literature I was reading.

Comment: Acceptable to whom?  Every claim has assumptions and (desired) conclusions.  It's just a matter of being clear about each.

Comment: Do you have to use formal logic for this?  Or would a mathematical proof suffice?

Comment: @Bram28 Would you mind showing me both?

Comment: @watchy See my Answer below ... I made a formal proof ... but placed comments (in green) next to the formal logic expressions of each line. By following the comments, you effectively have what is a more common 'mathematical' proof: it's less formal ... but would still count as a perfectly good proof in any math course. Indeed, it would basically be what masiewpao did in their Answer. The check marks are generated by the program I used ... the program checks whether on each line the indicated formal logic inference has been correctly applied. As you can see, it's all good! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's almost always helpful to write out definitions in these cases! What's an even integer? Well we say an integer $x$ is even if (and only if) $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\ \big(x = 2k\big)$.

So the statement is saying given any two integers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the property above (that is the property that *defines* them as being even), their sum is also even. Let's denote the sum $z = x + y$. This means $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\ \big(z = 2k\big)$. In other words, that the statement $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\ \big(x+y = 2k\big)$ is true.

Since the statement is really saying that for *any* two integers which are even, their sum is even, we are effectively saying

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}\  \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}\ \Big(\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\ \big(x = 2k\big) \land \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\ \big(y = 2k\big) \rightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\ \big(x+y = 2k\big)\Big)$$

I know when I first started writing proofs, I would often get confused about why things were universally quantified, when the word 'all' wasn't explicitly mentioned. But over time, you learn to understand the implicit quantification, and in this statement, it is exactly meant to be true for *any* two even integers.

---

Also the proof of the statement is easy: Supposing $x$ and $y$ are even, then we can write them as $x = 2k_1$ and $y = 2k_2$ for some integers $k_1$ and $k_2$. So their sum is of course $x+y = 2k_1 + 2k_2$ $= 2(k_1 + k_2)$. But we know any integer plus itself is again an integer, so $x+y = 2k_3$ for an integer $k_3 = k_2 + k_1$. Of course since we assumed nothing about $x$ and $y$ other than the fact that they were even, we have proven the statement for *all* pairs of even integers.

Comment: I improved the spacing after your quantifiers. Also, note that LaTeX bracket-sizing commands are ridiculous: `normal` < `big` < `Big` < `bigg` < ...

Comment: @user21820 Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, your statement is not an implication, but it can be expressed as a quantified formula in which the universal quantifier governs a logical implication.

Let $P(x)$ mean "$x$ is even". Then your statement can be written as

$$
\forall n, k \in \mathbb{Z} \quad \left(\, P(n) \land P(k) \implies P(n+k) \,\right).
$$

The clause governed by the universal quantifier has the structure you want. The hypothesis is $P(n) \land P(k)$ and the conclusion is $P(n+k)$.

This is an example of a formula in a [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic). In simple terms, first-order logic extends [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) which you are familiar with by adding quantifiers (such as $\forall$ meaning "for all"), predicates (such as $P(x)$ which we defined here to mean "$x$ is even"), functions (such as $+$) and constants (such as $0$ which we did not use here).

The statement can be proven for example in [Peano's arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms).

Comment: Ok, that was a helpful way of looking at the statement. After looking at so much conditional statements, I got confused. I wasn't quite sure what was p and what was q. Does a statement like this have a "formal" name, like conditional statements do? Also, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful. I'm not aware of a formal name for formulas of the structure above. Formulas that begin with a quantifier are often called [*quantified formulas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)), but this term applies irrespective of the structure of the internal clause (i.e. it does not need to be an implication for the formula to deserve the term).

Comment: Fixed. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for amending your post!

Comment: @user2715077: Although you stated in your question that you have seen a proof of the statement, I would say that you have actually *not* seen a proper proof. As Adam said, a proper proof will have to be done in a formal system such as PA (first-order Peano Arithmetic). In particular, a proper proof will necessarily have to feel like the one *masiewpao* sketched. But before you can even do formal proofs, you will of course have to learn how to use a deductive system for FOL (first-order logic). I strongly recommend [this Fitch-style system](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820).

Comment: Alternatively, if you prefer to have a long textbook to work through, you can try [Language, Proof and Logic](http://homepages.uc.edu/~martinj/Symbolic_Logic/341%20Syllabus,%20Textbook,%20Handouts,%20Notes/LPL%20textbook.pdf), which also describes a Fitch-style system from a variant tradition (so don't try both at the same time as it may be confusing). If you have any inquiries about my post or about LPL, feel free to ask me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics)! =)

Comment: @user21820 The proofs I have seen use definitions from Elementary Number Theory. Thank you for your recommendations! I will definitely take a look at them.

Answer (score 2):

It could be the case that you've only studied propositional (also called *zeroth-order*) logic so far. If so, then we may reword your statement slightly and write something like "if $p$ is even and $q$ is even, then $p+q$ is even too".

Nevertheless, such a formalution may feel lacking in some sense. I believe the culprit here is the word "always". To me this suggests something else is at play. The statement as you give it can't really be fully captured using propositional logic, because it contains an implicit *quantifier*. This means we have to use *predicate logic* (also called *first-order logic*) here. Note that what your statement *really* says is that **for any** even integers $p$ and $q$, $p+q$ is also even. Notationally, "*for all* $x$" is written as $\forall x$. Let's write $E(x)$ to express the property of being even. Hence, in formal notation, your statement becomes: $$\forall p \forall q \big(E(p)\land E(q)\to E(p+q)\big).$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formal proof ... with the comments making up a mathematical proof:

[image]

Comment: Very cool! Thanks. What program did you use to do this?

Comment: @watchy It's called Fitch. It comes with a commercial book and software package called Language, Proof, and Logic.... for $55 you can get the online version: pdf of book, this Fitch program, but also Boole (a program for making truth-tables), and Tarski's World (a pretty cool program that really teaches you to read and write logic expressions: you create block worlds on the basis of given logic expressions, and you can translate those block worlds back into logic expression)

Comment: I'll take a look at that package.

Comment: @watchy Yeah, I saw your comment that you were looking at metamath ... so I am glad you brought that up, since my recommendation is not to start there if you really want to go into formal proofs: the proofs are super detailed and, as a result, they are hard to follow. The notation isn't the easiest either. Indeed, metamath is for serious logicians/mathematicians who really want to break things down down to the absolute 'deepest' axioms of logic and math .. very cool! (I frequently visit metamath myself!) ... but not for beginners

Comment: So yes, I would recommend starting with something more friendly to a beginner. There is plenty of free stuff out there as well. Here is one that has a text and proof editor/checker, all for free: http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. It seemed to be extremely detailed. Cool, but hard to follow. The one thing that was confusing me was how different definitions can be. Like on metamath the definitions were extremely strict, I guess you might say. But yet, they are still considered definitions. I am not exactly sure what to call them. Are they axioms, or just definitions written in set theory. Nice to know things don't have to be that hard!

Comment: @watchy Right. The proof you linked in your post is over 70 steps ... and almost every step is some kind of 'derived inference' ... they start with ZFC (so even numbers are defined in terms of sets), and a very small set of elementary axioms for logic itself ... and so if you were to break down the proof to all that, this proof would be thousands of lines long. So, instead they build Lemma upon Lemma upon Lemma. Basically each step in the proof you linked is an application of some earlier proven Lemma. All very precise ... but not exactly consumer-friendly

Comment: @watchy The other thing is with the expressions themselves. As you can see, they have to explicitly specify that we're talking about whole numbers (integers Z), whereas in my proof I left that domain implicit. This adds another layer of complexity that in a way 'detracts' from the 'core' of the proof. Instead, my formal proof is still fairly compatible with a mathematical proof ... as I showed by placing the comments next to it, you can 'follow' the formal logic proof reasonably well.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean about how it detracts. Well, man, I can't thank you enough for the help. Like I said, I just started learning this stuff on my own, so your comments are much appreciated.

Comment: @watchy  Glad I could help out!  I too largely learned this stuff on my own :)  Also, since you seem to be a fairly new to Math.SE: if you think that some given answer answers your question to your satisfaction, you can accept that answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: I am not OP, but I found this fascinating. Can I ask between steps 19 and 20, what exactly is the program suggesting? I don't quite follow using existential instantiation from the premise Even(a,b) to the conclusion Even(a,b)?

Comment: @masiewpao Yeah, that's always a bit of a weird step ... and it's partly a function of the details of this particular proof system.  In other proof system, lines 7 and 11 would be considered the lines where the existential elimination (or instantiation) would take place, but in this proof system those are considered mere assumptions (E.g. line 7: "Let's assume that c is one of those objects object for which a = 2 * c" ... (and note, in math we know that there is of course exactly one object c for which this is the coase, but logic doesn;t know anything about that ..)

Comment: Yeah, I was expecting EI at exactly 7 and 11, but I now notice that it doesn't actually! This was a very interesting answer, thank you!

Comment: @masiewpao So, when you have reached line 19,  you know that a + b is even on the assumption that d is *some* object for which b = 2*d. Which one exactly? Well, we don;t know, it's just one of those objects for which this is the case.  But, that is in fact the key to now being able to go to line 20: since we didn;t assume (on line 11) anything about d other than that it was one of those for which b = 2d, then given the fact that we were able to derive from that assumption that a + b is even, we can then also say that a + b is even on the basis of the very existential statement on line 10.

Comment: Ah I see, so 19 to 20 uses the fact that $d$ is essentially an arbitrary element from the set $\{x: b = 2 \cdot x\}$? I haven't studied formal logic, so I find it interesting that we don't use EI at 7 instead. My understanding was that EI allows us to introduce a new symbol, say $c$, that would allow us to reason with it without having to worry about whether it is the only example satisfying the statement or not.

Comment: Thanks for posting a proof based on LPL (which I also recommended [in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8156839))! However, please do not send students for forallx, as many students who read it came away with deep misconceptions of the deductive rules for quantifiers involving constant-symbols. CC @masiewpao

Comment: @user21820 Really?!  Wow, ok, good to know.  So yeah, I admit I haven't used forall x  myself but I did hear some good things about it.... and of course it's free :) Thanks for your perspective. I should really look at it before I recommend it again (if ever ...)

Comment: Sorry I missed your comment until now. One of those confused by forallx said [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/44058?m=43213528#43213528) based on the conceptually incorrect explanation in forallx. The Calgary version you linked to has the same errors; "21.2 Names" explains 'names' as if they are constant-symbols, which is confirmed by "26.2 Terms and formulas", and "26.1 Expressions" lists $a,...,r$ as names, but "32.4 Universal introduction" wrongly says that the ∀intro rule applies to any name $c$ not occurring "in an undischarged assumption". [cont]

Comment: [cont] But as I mentioned in chat, [PA−](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations) has constant-symbols $0,1$ and the axiom $0<1$, but we certainly cannot invoke ∀intro to get $∀x(x<1)$! Furthermore, the 'motivation' given in that section for the ∀intro rule seems completely bogus and circular to me...