# How do sets work and what are elements of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, intuition

In naive set theory, any collection of "objects" is a set. Thus, $\{1,2\},\{A,B,C,D\},\mathbf{N}$ are all sets since they are a collection of objects. We say that an object is an element of a set, if it is one of the objects in the set. The word "is" in this sentence refers to "is equal to" as far as I know. Therefore the set of complex numbers $\{ a+ib \ | \ a,b \in \mathbf{R}\}$ also contains the element object $e^{2 \pi i}$. I now wondered if I can visualize any set this way. What I mean by this is, when working with abstract sets, can I visualize this set as a "complete collection" of objects, as in the case of $\mathbf{N}$ or $\mathbf{C}$ of which I don't explicitly know what the elements exactly are? More precisely, can I visualize an abstract set $S$ as a complete list of abstract elements $s$ of $S$? If I could not visualize it this way, then I couldn't imagine what the set $$A:=\{s \in S \ | \phi(s)\}$$ would be for some property $\phi(s)$. Clearly this would be the collection of all $s$ that satisfy this property and are contained in $S$, but it is then impossible to say which elements are in $S$, wouldn't this then be problematic?

Furthermore I wondered about the following: when proving a property for every element of a set $A$, does it then suffice to show it for the elements in one "complete form"? If so, why is that the case? For example, if I wanted to show a property for all elements of {1,2} it would suffice to show it for $1$ and $2$, or if I wanted to show a property for all natural numbers, it would suffice to show it for $1$,$2$,$3$,... or every "$n \in \mathbf{N}$". However, there could be elements that are not "listed" in this set, such as the $e^{2 \pi i}$ example. Why have I shown it for those objects as well? The intuition would be, that they are the same object, and just different "names". Would the formal explanation be that if there is a "hidden" name in the set $S$, then it is equal to one of the "explicit" elements and thus has the exact same properties. Thus, if I have shown a property for all "explicit" elements in $S$, it follows for any form of the elements.

Edit: (Adding a problem) As far as I see it, there are the following two interpretations: $(1)$ A set $S$ contains objects that are denoted by symbols which I will call "initial presentation" of (the objects in) $S$. An example would be writing the natural numbers as $\{1,2,3,4,...\}$ or $\mathbf{C}$ as $\{a+ib \ | \ a,b \in \mathbf{R}\}$. These symbols **are** the objects of the set and I can rename those objects by using ":=" which defines a new symbol to be the same object as the one on the right side. Thus when writing things like $e^{2 \pi i}:=1$ I define $e^{2 \pi i}$ to be the object $1$. Thus one would have that $e^{2 \pi i}$ is in $\mathbf{C}$ since it is literally just a different name for the same object namely $1$.

$(2)$ A set $S$ again has an initial presentation by the symbols it contains. This time, however, the symbols are not the objects, but rather representing objects of the set. I imagine these objects as points in a space and the symbols standing over the points, where two symbols represent the same object, if they are connectable by a line which would mean that "both symbols refer to the same object". Thus, there would be a point named $1$ and a point named $e^{2 \pi i}$ and they are connected in the set $\mathbf{C}$ since by definition $e^{2 \pi i}=1$. More generally, if I define a new symbol for an existing one, I create a path from the original object, in this case named $1$, to the new symbol, in this case named $e^{2 \pi i}$. This distincts the words "symbol" and "objects" more strictly than $(1)$, but is also harder to understand and also complex to use in my opinion. Now when a set contains one of the symbols, it means that it contains the object represented by this symbol and thus all the other paths as well, which would explain why $e^{2 \pi i} \in \mathbf{C}$. An intuitive problem I see here though is, what is the difference between ${1,2} and any other set containing two elements, say {8,9}? They are both just symbols for two objects (whatever an object is) or more precisely points in my example, that are referred to by different symbols. Thus, in my image, one would have two points with different names in this set and that is the entire difference.

Comment: The word "is" is ambiguous: "Plato is a philosopher" does **not** mean "Plato is equal to a philosopher" but "Plato belongs to the class of philosophers" or "The property 'to be a philosopher' applies to Plato".

Comment: Regarding $A = \{ s \in S  \mid \phi(s) \}$, this definition "carve out" the set $A$ form the already existing set $S$ specifying a "property" $\phi(x)$. Thus, we already have (know) what $S$ is.

Comment: To prove that $P(x)$ holds for every element of a set $A$ we can check all elements of $A$, **IF** the number of elements of $A$ is *finite*. But, in general, we need a proof.

Comment: If we want to prove e.g. that **every** $n \in \mathbb N$ is Even, it is **not** sufficient to show it for $2,4,6,\ldots$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My example of $\mathbf{N}$ was chosen badly, sorry. What exactly do you mean by "we already have (know) what $S$ is"? I think this goes in the direction I am looking for. If we "know" what $S$ is, i.e. know what objects it contains I can "list" them (not literally but with "..." notation) and thus make statements about the elements. If I don't know the elements, then I don't know how a statement regarding the elements would make sense.

Comment: If you know what the set $E$ of even number is, you must be able to check if a number $n$ whatever is even... The check must involve some "formula/property". To check if it occurs in the "list" can be not feasible.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I edited my question and added a problem. Perhaps you have time to comment on that, thank you in advance!

Comment: "These symbols are the objects of the set ..." *Symbols* are not the objects (elements) of the set: they are the **names** of the objects of the set. Thus, the set $\{ 1, \text {one} \}$ has only one element: the number *one*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote: "Would the formal explanation be that if there is a 'hidden' name in the set $S$, then it is equal to one of the 'explicit' elements and thus has the exact same properties. Thus, if I have shown a property for all "explicit" elements in $S$, it follows for any form of the elements."

There are no hidden names in $S$, because there are no names in $S$ at all.  We may use names to specify what the elements of $S$ are, but the elements of $S$ are the objects named by those names, not the names themselves.

So, for example, if the number 1 is an element of $S$, then $e^{2\pi i}$ is also an element of $S$.  That's not because 1 is an "explicit" element and $e^{2\pi i}$ is a "hidden" element that has all the same properties.  It's because "1" and "$e^{2\pi i}$" are two different names for the very same object, the number 1.  And it is that number, not the name "1", that is an element of $S$.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "object"?

Comment: I wish I could.  This is one of the great unsolved problems in the philosophy of mathematics.  Most mathematicians imagine that there are such things as mathematical objects--numbers, sets, functions, and so on--and when we do mathematics we are studying those objects and their properties.  My answer was written from that point of view.  But what, exactly, are these mathematical objects?  There is no widespread agreement.

Comment: Could I then think about all of this in the following way: Let $S$ be an arbitrary set, then the elements of $S$ are presented in some "initial" form, e.g. the natural numbers with numbers $1,2,3,4,...$ the complex numbers by $a+ib$ and so on. There would now be two ways. I could either think of the presentation as the name for the underlying object (whatever that would be) or I could interpret them to be the object itself (I don't think this makes a difference?).

Comment: It is possible to rename those symbols, as we do all the time by variables and expressions such as $e^{2 \pi i}$ in my example. When renaming those initial objects, one usually uses the notation ":=" which then means that they are by definition the same object, or more precisely that $e^{2 \pi i}$ is a symbol for the object $1$, if I want to view $1$ not just as a symbol for a more abstract object, but as an object itself. This would make it probably more intuitive.

Comment: I could also view it the other way, meaning that $1$ is also just a symbol for an object (but for what object? What makes it clear what $1$ stands for?). If this is the case, however, I don't see whats different between the set $\{1,2\}$ and the set $\{8,9\}$.

Comment: I added an edit in my original question, perhaps that clarifies my comments. Thank you for taking the time and helping me though, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

In response to your edit:  Your option (1), that the mathematical objects *are* the symbols, is one way to think of mathematical objects.  But there are difficulties with this view.  For example, most mathematicians would say that there are uncountably many real numbers but only countably many expressions that name real numbers.  So there are uncountably many real numbers that are unnameable.  What are those numbers?  There are no symbols for them.

I would guess that most mathematicians find option (2) more natural.  You find it harder to understand, perhaps because you can't bring yourself to believe in the mathematical objects.  You still write things like "Now when a set contains one of the symbols," indicating that you find it difficult to get away from your idea that sets contain symbols, not objects.  Your view of mathematical objects in (2) seems to be that they are just featureless points, invented to satisfy my insistence that symbols stand for objects, but indistinguishable except for the symbols attached to them.  So to you, $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{8, 9\}$ seem the same--each consists of two such points.  That is not how most mathematicians think of mathematical objects.  To most mathematicians, the mathematical objects exist and have all of their properties independent of any symbols we may attach to them.  The numbers 1, 2, 8, and 9 are different objects, with different properties, and they had those properties before people assigned the symbols "1", "2", "8", and "9" to them.

You might enjoy reading G. H. Hardy's view of this in his book *A Mathematician's Apology*.  The whole book is worth reading, but here is what he says in Section 22 of the book:

> In the first place, I shall speak of ‘physical reality’, and here
> again I shall be using the word in the ordinary sense. By physical
> reality I mean the material world, the world of day and night,
> earthquakes and eclipses, the world which physical science tries to
> describe.
>
> I hardly suppose that, up to this point, any reader is
> likely to find trouble with my language, but now I am near to more
> difficult ground. For me, and I suppose for most mathematicians, there
> is another reality, which I will call ‘mathematical reality’; and
> there is no sort of agreement about the nature of mathematical
> reality among either mathematicians or philosophers. Some hold that
> it is ‘mental’ and that in some sense we construct it, others that it
> is outside and independent of us. A man who could give a convincing
> account of mathematical reality would have solved very many of the
> most difficult problems of metaphysics. If he could include physical
> reality in his account, he would have solved them all.
>
> I should not
> wish to argue any of these questions here even if I were competent to
> do so, but I will state my own position dogmatically in order to avoid
> minor misapprehensions. I believe that mathematical reality lies
> outside us, that our function is to discover or *observe* it, and that
> the theorems which we prove, and which we describe grandiloquently as
> our ‘creations’, are simply our notes of our observations.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the perspective is that $\mathbf{N}$ exists (before any notation of the elements is given; somewhat when first defining this) and we call this the natural numbers. We call $\mathbf{N}$ the natural numbers. We now know (why?) that $\mathbf{N}$ contains objects as a set and we want to have symbolic expressions for those objects. Thus I say that one of the objects is $0$ called the zero object and also that the succession of any natural number is a natural number, meaning $s(0)$ is a natural number, $s(s(0))$ as well and so on.

Comment: I now define $1:=s(0), 2:=s(1)$ and so on. This means that I have now defined symbolic expressions for those objects. However, when having an abstract set $S$, this becomes more diffcult. What are the objects in $S$? Even if I have symbols for elements of $S$, can I always say what the objects are, or do I have to say something like the following. (assume that $s \in S$ is an object of $S$; this means that the symbol $s$ stands for some object in $S$). Define $t:=s$. Does this mean that $t$ is defined to be the underlying object meant by $s$?

Comment: In a context in which $S$ is a set, but it has not been specified what set it is, the answer to the question "What are the objects in $S$?" is "We don't know."  So what?  In a context in which $n$ is a natural number, but no particular value has been assigned to $n$, if you ask the question "What are the divisors of $n$?", the answer is "We don't know."  Whatever number $n$ is, it has divisors, even if we don't know what they are.  And whatever set $S$ is, it has elements (if it's not the empty set), even if we don't know what they are.

Comment: This discussion has gotten far more philosophical than I intended.  My impression is that you are a student of math, and you are having trouble understanding mathematical writing about sets because you are thinking of a set as collections of symbols that we specify as its elements when we define the set.  I am simply trying to suggest that you will find mathematical writing about sets easier to understand if you stop thinking about sets that way.  There are deep philosophical questions about what, exactly, mathematical objects are, but you don't need to answer those to read about sets.

Comment: @DanVelleman: You may be interested in looking at [my Fitch-style foundational system for mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820), which includes the deductive rules for many-sorted FOL and a Set Theory that allows urelements and has the same strength as ZFC.