# How to prove there are no natural numbers between 0 and 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

I've come up with a proof to the statement \begin{equation}\sim \exists a\in \mathbb{N}: 0<a<1\end{equation} And my question is: **Is this proof correct?**

In the proof we assume:

- $0\in \mathbb{N}$
- **Trichotomy:** $\forall (s,t)\in \mathbb{N}^{2}: s<t\oplus s=t\oplus t<s$. Where $\oplus$ is an *exclusive or*.
- $\forall s\in \mathbb{N}: s+1\ne 0$
- $\forall s\in \mathbb{N}: 0\leq s$*
- $\forall s\in \mathbb{N}: 1\leq s+1$*
- $p\vee q\iff \sim q\implies q$ where $p$ and $q$ are propositions and $\sim q$ is the negation of $q$.

**Remark.** The asterisked properties need to be show beforehand.

***Proof.*** By induction on $a$ we'll show that \begin{align*}\forall a\in \mathbb{N}: a<1\implies a=0\tag{1}\end{align*}.

**Base case:** Trivially \begin{align*}a=0\implies \Big(a<1\implies a=0\Big)\tag{2}\end{align*}
**Inductive step:** Let us notice that indeed\begin{align*}k+1<1\implies k+1=0\tag{3}\end{align*}because of $\forall s\in \mathbb{N}: 1\leq s+1$ and $\forall s\in \mathbb{N}: s+1\ne 0$. Then,\begin{align*}\Big(\exists k\in \mathbb{N}: k<1\implies k=0\Big)\implies (3)\tag{4}\end{align*}As a result from $(2)$ and $(4)$ it follows $(1)$, according to the principle of mathematical induction.

Furthermore, we see \begin{align*}(1)\iff \forall a\in \mathbb{N}:1\leq a\ \vee a=0\iff \sim \exists a\in \mathbb{N}: 0<a<1\end{align*}Meaning, *there are no natural numbers between $0$ and $1$*.

Comment: Aren't natural numbers by definition 'those used for counting', i.e. $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, meaning there are none between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @TymonMieszkowski Since by assumption, $0\in \mathbb{N}$, then it must be $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. The Wikipedia article [Natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) states: "Some definitions, including the standard ISO $80000-2$,$^{[4][a]}$ begin the natural numbers with $0$,"

Comment: @Somos but there are still none between $0$ and $1$, unless we redefine what numbers are in the set, right?

Comment: @TymonMieszkowski Yes, there are none, but the question is how to **prove** that statement **given** the assumptions.

Comment: I think it might help to add exactly what axiom (or axiom schema) you use for induction. Your argument is *fine* conceptually (although it has some extraneous components), but I feel like the useful criticism of the proof probably depends pretty heavily on your precise notion of induction, which makes it hard to productively answer this question without it defining induction.

Comment: Indeed, validity of proof by induction is another assumption being (silently) made. Well-ordering is an alternative assumption. If there exists $a$, $0<a<1$, then by well-ordering there's a least such $a$, but $a^2$ (is easily proved to be) smaller than $a$ and also between zero and one, contradiction.

Comment: You probably want to mention explicitly which [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) you are using in your proof.

Comment: In lieu of the messy and almost useless wikipedia article linked by Somos, look at the axioms under "Peano Arithmetic" [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820) and determine which you are using and which you are not. What is important is that you understand rigorous logical reasoning and can identify exactly what axioms/rules you are using. (Note that PA− proves the desired fact already, and logicians typically consider PA− as the base system upon which to add induction.)