# How do I prove the corollary to the multiplicative property of $0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

My elementary high school algebra textbook states:

If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $a = 0$ or $b = 0$,

then $ab = 0$.

Follows directly as a corollary to: if $a$ is a real number, then $a \cdot 0 = 0$ and $0 \cdot a = 0$.

How does the first statement follow directly as a corollary?

Comment: Rewrite the second statement as follows: "If $a,b$ are real numbers, then $a\cdot 0=0$ and $0\cdot b=0$."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be the correct approach?

Proof

1. a and b are real numbers; Given
2. a = 0 or b = 0;  Given
3. If a and b are real numbers, then a • 0 = 0 and 0 • b = 0;    Rewritten
   second statement
4. Therefore a • b = 0;    Steps 2 and 3

Comment: The intuitive idea is correct, but if you want to know precisely how to formalize the logical reasoning, then you need to learn a full deductive system for FOL such as [this Fitch-style system](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820).