# Common phrases in proof writing

Tags: proof-writing, notation

I am a little confused over the differences between phrases in proof writing. They are: 'Fix an abitrary $x \in S$', 'Fix $x \in S$', 'Let $x \in S$'. I would like to know what each of them means. In addition to this, I'd like further clarification on the two different interpretations of let $x \in S$ (in regards to particular and non-specific $x$'s, whether $x$ is an arbitrary or not constant). If I wanted $x$ to be a specific constant would I still write Let $x \in S$, or is that only for an arbitrary element $x$? When we write $x \in S$, what extra information do we have to give for $x$ to be non-arbitrary and specific?

Comment: The three phrases $$\text{Fix an abitrary $x\in S$.}$$ $$\text{Fix $x\in S$.}$$ $$\text{Let $x\in S$.}$$ mean the same. If  authors don't not want $x$ to be arbitrary they better say so.

Comment: Alright thanks Kurt. Is there ever a case where $x \in S$ means $x$ is not arbitrary? Or is it always an arbitrary $x$. I find it hard to find a case where $x$ is a truly fixed value (not arbitrary).

Comment: That's exactly what I am criticising about your question. Human language has room for interpretation. We are not robots that compile a program code. Again: if there is *ever* a case where $x$ means *not* arbitrary your authors better say so. If they don't tradition tells us $x$ is arbitrary.

Comment: 'If they don't tradition tells' that is what I was looking for. Thanks. The 'default setting' is arbitrary and that's why most proof writing doesn't use the word, its so common usage it is almost assumed.

Comment: It’s more like: if no further information is given, how could it *not* be arbitrary.

Comment: Q. "When we write $x\in S$
, what extra information do we have to give for $x$
 to be non-arbitrary and specific?" A. Example: for a subset of $S$ you could give the extra information that $x$ is in that subset. Obviously that subset could be a singleton. In that case $x$ is totally not arbitrary.

Comment: Q: 'If I write $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $y = 2x$, we would then start to call $x$ a variable. However earlier on we called $x$ an arbitrary number? Can we call a free variable like $x$ an arbitrary number?

Comment: Why not? $\phantom{.}$ Honestly: this discussion is happening in a vacuum. I would prefer to discuss concrete examples from the literature where you see *mathematical* (not linguistic!) *ambiguities*.

Comment: @Malady "if no further information is given, how could it not be arbitrary" Debatably, by using the word "choose" rather than "fix" or "let". As in, something like "By the fundamental theorem of algebra, choose $x\in\mathbb C$ satisfying $x^2-2x+1=0$. Then..."

Comment: All your logic-related questions are completely answered once you learn a proper deductive system for FOL, such as the one at this thread: [Predicate logic: How do you self-check the logical structure of your own arguments?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681857).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Fixing” a value just means to not treat it as changing. An “arbitrary fixed value” may initially seem counterintuitive, but it just means that the value is *one specific* yet arbitrary value. Essentially, the value has no properties other than its membership in the set, and we are looking at only it. And “let $a$ equal…” simply means to treat the symbol $a$ as a stand-in for what proceeds. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Under the context of induction proofs we may write 'Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$' is that the same as 'Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$'? How do we know Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$ doesn't refer to a specific $k$ but rather an arbitrary one?

Comment: Usually, for the proof it doesn’t truly matter. I would interpret “fix $k$” to mean that we are now going to look at one specific value of $k$, *but that value is still arbitrary*. Imagine we have a matrix whose columns are indexed by $i$. If we fix $i$, all of a sudden we just have one column, *but it is an arbitrary column*. Nothing truly changed, just how we were thinking about it.

Comment: That's the thing, if we use a letter like $k$, to me, it means $k$ is always arbitrary. If we wanted to write 'Fix $k=2$' then that is obviously TRULY fixed and not arbitrary. Is it not pretty ambiguous to use a letter such as $x$ or $k$ for a true fixed value, i.e the letter is always a stand in for an arbitrary value?

Comment: Fixed and arbitrary *are not exclusive*. For my matrix example, fixing $i$ did not require us to give a value to $i$. All it did was shift our focus to the columns of the matrix.

Comment: Can you give an example of using a letter like $x$ or $i$, fixing the value but it not being arbitrary?

Comment: “Let $i$ and $-i$ be the roots of the polynomial $x^2+1$.” i is fixed, but certainly not arbitrary.

Comment: I was referring to using $i$ as a variable, not the imaginary unit.

Comment: You asked me for an example of fixing a symbol to a non-arbitrary value. I gave you such an example. If $i$ is taken to be a variable *then it cannot be fixed.* Those are simply opposites.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted but do you have any more example?

Comment: $e$ and $\pi$ and all sorts of other things. We use symbols to mean things, sometimes we use them to mean non-arbitrary things.

Comment: Finally, I'm struggling to find an example where we might use notation like $x \in S$ for specific $x$. If that's all that's given, isn't it assumed $x$ is arbitrary?