# Showing permutation does not change output of commutative operation (recursion theorem)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, recursion, binary-operations

(In what follows, NB that $\mathbb{N}^\times$ is the positive natural numbers, and $\mathbb{N}$ includes 0.)

I am working on Exercise 1 of Amann and Escher *Analysis I*, and the problem is essentially asking:

> Show that if $X$ is a set with a commutative and associative (addition) operation defined thereon, then $\sum_{j=0}^n x_j = \sum_{j=0}^n x_{\sigma(j)}$ where $\sigma$ is any permutation (bijection) of $\{0,1,...,n\}$.

I am really baffled as to how to even start. It's *obviously* true, but I need to prove it using the recursion theorem of set theory (Amann and Escher's Proposition 5.11). I understand how the standard sum notation ought to interpreted. I've written:

> We must first interpret the notation $\sum_{j=0}^n x_{\sigma(j)}$. Given the definition for general associative operations in Example 5.12, one is led to presume that this notation refers to a recursive definition which is induced by the original. The original $\sum_{j=0}^n x_j$ is technically defined by Prop 5.11 in terms of some sequence $x_0,x_1,x_2,...$ in $X$ and some sequence of functions $V_n: X^n \to X, (y_0,...,y_{n-1}) \mapsto y_{n-1} + x_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}^\times$. Now take the unique function $f: \mathbb{N} \to X$ (by Prop 5.11) for which $f(0) = x_0$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(n+1) = V_{n+1}(f(0),...,f(n)) = f(n) + x_{n+1}$. Then define $\sum_{j=0}^n x_j := f(n)$.

I am guessing that I need to interpret the notation $\sum_{j=0}^n x_{\sigma(j)}$ somehow in terms of a recursive definition related to the sequence $V_n$ which defined $\sum_{j=0}^n x_j$ (and then perhaps I need to use induction somehow?), but I can't see how given that $\sigma$ is defined for fixed $n$, among other things. **Can anyone provide a hint or even a sketch of a proof, with careful attention paid to what $\sum_{j=0}^n x_{\sigma(j)}$ really means?**

For those interested in all the gory details of what I have, I have attached a couple pictures of relevance, but hopefully my question is valid as it stands.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can start by noticing that for any sum we can bring an arbitrary term to the front and get the same sum. This can be proved with just induction and the commutativity axiom since all we are doing is repeatedly swapping two terms in the sum. Then, given a permuted sum of length n, we can reduce the problem to one for a permutation of length n - 1 by moving the ith term to the front where i is the index of 0. Then the result follows from another induction.

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t quite follow @scleaver if you get the chance, would it be possible to flesh out some of the details in an answer? My main sticking point right now is even in giving a definition (recursive definition) for the permitted sum, as for the “native” sum.

Comment: I mean permuted* above of course.

Comment: It seems sometimes in the question is written $\sum_{j=1}^n$ instead of $\sum_{j=0}^n$.

Comment: I think that since Exercise 1 concerns fixed $n$, Proposition 5.11 is not needed for it.

Comment: As I see, in order to define $\sum_{j=0}^n x_j$, the addition should be associative.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: That's incorrect. From a proper logical viewpoint, the summation can be rigorously defined (but was **not** done in the cited text) regardless of whether addition is associative or not.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, I meant the definition from the cited text, with respect to which, I guess, Exercise 1 should be solved.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: I see now that you are talking about the lack of brackets in the cited text, which merely makes it wrong or misleading, and your comment too is wrong or misleading, because ultimately there must be some definition of what "x+y+z" means, not to say "x+y+...+z" with the common but nebulous ellipsis. And once that definition is precisely stated, one would see that the summation can be defined exactly the same way *without relying on associativity*!

Comment: @user21820 Yes, given a binary operation $\odot$ or $+$ on a set, the definition of $\bigodot_{j=0}^{n}$ or $x+y+...+z$ can be provided recursively via brackets. By in the *cited* text this definition is provided only for an *associative* operation $\odot$, so if I consider $\bigodot_{j=0}^{n}$ or $\sum_{j=0}^{n}$ then I have to assume that $\odot$ or $+$ is associative.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: Ok that's satisfactory. But I stand by my assertion that the cited text is wrong or misleading. And that isn't the only problem. I'll post an answer to give the technically precise details.

Comment: @AlexRavsky It's my apologies, I should have noted that the addition operation on this set is assumed to be associative. I will edit to reflect.

Comment: @user21820 My apologies to you too, please see the above.

Comment: @EE18 Hopefully the answer I wrote is useful and not as incorrect as it is imprecise. The definition of $\sum_{j=0}^n x_{\sigma(n)}$ is the same as the one given for $\sum_{j=0}^n x_{\sigma(n)}$ in the book, just using the sequence $\{x_{\sigma(n)}\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ instead of $x$.

Comment: I am actually crafting a reply to your answer right now :) thank you very much, it *is* very helpful to me. @scleaver

Comment: @AlexRavsky: Just to let you know, I've posted my answer, and the issue about implicit associativity may be an attempt by the cited text to evade explaining (✻) in my post. It's good that we had this discussion because I think it's worth seeing clearly what is involved. Claiming that we can drop brackets due to associativity is as strong as claiming (✻), and unsurprisingly proving it requires induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I don't believe you have sufficient foundation in basic logic to tackle such problems. This is not your fault, naturally, because it is hard to find good teachers. For you to truly grasp how everything in mathematics is built, you would need to learn basic FOL (first-order logic) *including an actually usable deductive system* such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820).

As part of that, you need to understand precisely the logical underpinnings of definitions, which are captured by definitorial expansion. An important example is the pair-projection function-symbols `first` and `second` where `first(p)` and `second(p)` are the first and second items in `p` for any ordered pair `p`. (These can be defined rigorously [in this way](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/77161?m=59684470#59684470).) We can then use the notation `( S x , T y ↦ E(x,y) )` as short for `( (S×T) i ↦ E(first(i),second(i)) )` and similarly use the notation `( S x , T y , U z ↦ E(x,y,z) )` as short for `( (S×(T×U)) i ↦ E(first(i),first(second(i)),second(second(i))) )`.

The proposition 5.11 that you cited from your book is actually a very shoddy one from a logical viewpoint. It has the nebulous ellipsis ("..."), which in general is imprecise and results in shoddy conceptual understanding. The real [general recursion theorem](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/77161?m=63082018#63082018) is:

`∀A,S∈set ∀c∈A→S ∀f∈A×(ℕ×S)→S ∃g∈A×ℕ→S ∀x∈A` 
  `( g(x,0) = c(x) ∧ ∀k∈ℕ ( g(x,k+1) = f(x,(k,g(x,k))) ) ).`

This allows you to construct the summation fully rigorously like this (skipping minor steps):

```
Let SumZ = ( (ℕ⁺→ℂ) f ↦ ( ℕ k ↦ 0 ) ).
Let SumA = ( (ℕ⁺→ℂ) f , ℕ k , (ℕ→ℂ) g ↦ ( ℕ i ↦ i ≤ k ? g(i) : g(k)+f(k+1) ) ).
[Now we apply the general recursion theorem on SumZ and SumA.]
Let SumP∈(ℕ⁺→ℂ)×ℕ→(ℕ→ℂ) such that
  ∀f∈ℕ⁺→ℂ ( SumP(f,0) = SumZ(f) ∧ ∀k∈ℕ ( SumP(f,k+1) = SumA(f,(k,SumP(f,k)) ) ).
Let Sum = ( (ℕ⁺→ℂ) f , ℕ k ↦ SumP(f,k)(k) ).
Given f∈ℕ⁺→ℂ:
  Sum(f,0) = SumP(f,0)(0) = SumZ(f)(0) = ( ℕ k ↦ 0 )(0) = 0.
  Given k∈ℕ:
    Sum(f,k+1) = SumP(f,k+1)(k+1) = SumA(f,(k,SumP(f,k)))(k+1)
     = SumP(f,k)(k)+f(k+1) = Sum(f,k)+f(k+1).
  ∀k∈ℕ ( Sum(f,k+1) = Sum(f,k)+f(k+1) ).
∀f∈ℕ⁺→ℂ ( Sum(f,0) = 0 ∧ ∀k∈ℕ ( Sum(f,k+1) = Sum(f,k)+f(k+1) ) ).
[We have now obtained the Sum operator with its desired properties.]
```

I want to emphasize that *nowhere in this 100% rigorous construction* do we rely on assuming associativity or commutativity of + on ℂ! Only when we want to prove some further properties of Sum would we need those.

~ ~ ~

Now on to your question. As a beginner you should probably not use subscripts if you are dealing with a genuine function. You can see already that the `Sum` operator as defined above requires two inputs, one being a function from `ℕ⁺→ℂ` and the other being a natural number that represents the index to sum to. Don't think of it as $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i$. Think of it as $\sum_{i=1}^k f(i)$, which is what it truly is.

Then everything regarding permutations would become crystal-clear too. You want to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^k f(i) = \sum_{i=1}^k f(σ(i))$ for every $f{∈}ℕ⁺{→}ℂ$ and permutation σ on $[1..k]$. Of course, $\sum_{i=1}^k f(σ(i)) = \sum_{i=1}^k (f∘σ)(i)$, and so you ought to know precisely what that means. If conventional notation is confusing, simply use the precise formal notation and it is clear.

In particular, you must supply `Sum` with a function from ℕ⁺→ℂ and the index to sum to. Given `f∈ℕ⁺→ℂ`, remember that `f(i)` is **not** a function, but `f` is, and so is `f∘σ`. For convenience, let's not ask for the summation operator to be able to handle functions whose domain is not ℕ⁺, otherwise the above definition of `Sum` is insufficient. (Your cited text makes this mistake as well.) So eliminate this problem, we can define a permutation of $[1..k]$ as a function $f{∈}ℕ⁺{→}ℕ⁺$ such that $Im(f{↾}[1..k]) = [1..k]$.

Rigorously:

```
Let Perm = ( ℕ k ↦ { f : f∈ℕ⁺→ℕ⁺ ∧ ∀x∈[1..k] ∃i∈[1..k] ( f(i) = x ) } ).
Given f∈ℕ⁺→ℂ and k∈ℕ and σ∈Perm(k):
  σ∈ℕ⁺→ℕ⁺.
  f∘σ∈ℕ⁺→ℂ.
  If k = 0:
    Sum(f∘σ,k) = 0.
  If k > 0:
    k−1∈ℕ.
    Sum(f∘σ,k) = Sum(f∘σ,k−1)+(f∘σ)(k).
```

Now the desired theorem is:

`∀f∈ℕ⁺→ℂ ∀k∈ℕ ∀σ∈Perm(k) ( Sum(f,k) = Sum(f∘σ,k) ).`

How do we prove it? Ignoring all the other technical problems with the cited text, *scleaver* gives an intuitive method, but there is still a big problem: It is actually not at all easy to prove the theorem for a single arbitrary transposition. I will hence demonstrate an alternative approach:

For any permutation $σ$ on $[1..k]$ define $c(σ)$ to be the number of pairs $⟨i,j⟩$ from $[1..k]^2$ such that $i < j$ and $σ(i) > σ(j)$. It is easy to prove that:

1. If $c(σ) = 0$ then $σ(i) = i$ for every $i∈[1..k]$.
2. If $c(σ) > 0$ then there is some $d∈[1..k{−}1]$ such that $σ(d) > σ(d+1)$.

By strong induction along $ℕ$ we can assume that the theorem holds for any permutation $φ$ with $c(φ) < c(σ)$. If $c(σ) = 0$ then we are done. Otherwise by the above let $d∈[1..k{−}1]$ such that $σ(d) > σ(d+1)$. Let $σ'$ be the same as $σ$ except that $σ'(d) = σ(d+1)$ and $σ'(d+1) = σ(d)$. Then we can show that $c(σ') < c(σ)$, and so $\sum_{i=1}^k f(i) = \sum_{i=1}^k (f∘σ')(i)$. We also have:
  $\sum_{i=1}^k (f∘σ)(i)$
  $ = \Big( \big( \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} (f∘σ)(i) + (f∘σ)(d) \big) + (f∘σ)(d+1) \Big) + \sum_{i=d+2}^{k} (f∘σ)(i)$ [by (✻)]
  $ = \Big( \big( \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} (f∘σ')(i) + (f∘σ')(d+1) \big) + (f∘σ')(d) \Big) + \sum_{i=d+2}^{k} (f∘σ')(i)$
  $ = \Big( \big( \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} (f∘σ')(i) + (f∘σ')(d) \big) + (f∘σ')(d+1) \Big) + \sum_{i=d+2}^{k} (f∘σ')(i)$
    [by associativity and commutativity of + on ℂ]
  $ = \sum_{i=1}^k (f∘σ')(i)$ [by (✻)]
  $ = \sum_{i=1}^k f(i)$.

(✻) is one key property of summation that must be proven before you can do this kind of manipulation. It relies on associativity, but not commutativity, of + on ℂ. Also note that the "$\sum_{i=d+2}^{k}$" summation notation with a variable lower index can be defined in terms of the more basic summation notation with a fixed lower index of $1$. If you want to make it fully rigorous, you can either define it in terms of `Sum`, or in the first place define `Sum` to take an extra input for the lower index. Both are viable choices.

I have chosen not to formalize the entire theorem in full so that you can see enough to convince yourself of how it can be done, and if you are keen enough to try it you can ask me if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer user. I am leaving the house right now so I have had time only to skim it, but I look forward to reading through it later today. Just wanted to write this so you know I'm not ignoring it -- thank you for the effort and help on this one!

Comment: @EE18: You're welcome. By the way, you are not the first person to ask me about rigorous definition of summation, and it is an excellent question, so ignore the dismissive comments that some other people have made about your question. By the way, if you want to chat about this stuff, let me know and I'll give you access to the Basic Math chat-room.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that would be awesome if possible.

Comment: Much of this went above my head, but I have a number of links to explore, so thank you both for this answer (which gets me as close to understanding as I can at my current level) and for those links. Much to learn there is for me!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of what I had in mind in my comment, or something like it. I may be overcomplicating this but I'm trying to be explicit to avoid confusion over notation.

Let $x: \Bbb N \to X$ be a sequence and for all $n \in \Bbb N$ and all permutations $\sigma$ of length $n + 1$ define
$$\sum_{j=0}^nx_j := f(n)$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^nx_{\sigma(j)} := f_\sigma(n)$$
where $f$ is the sequences of partial sums defined as in the book which satisfy
$$f(0) = x_0$$
$$f(n) = f(n - 1) + x_n$$
and $f_\sigma$ is defined analogously so that it satisfies
$$f_\sigma(0) = x_{\sigma(0)}$$
$$f_\sigma(n) = f_\sigma(n - 1) + x_{\sigma(n)}$$
The claim is$$\forall n \in \Bbb N : \forall \sigma: \{0, 1, ...n \} \leftrightarrow \{0, 1, ...n \}:f(n) = f_\sigma(n)$$

The base case is trivial since if $n = 0$ then $\sigma: \{0\} \leftrightarrow \{0\}$ is the identity so $f(0) = f_\sigma(0) = x_0$. Now assume $n > 0$ and
$$\forall k < n: \forall \sigma: \{1, 2, ...k\} \leftrightarrow \{1, 2, ...k\}:f(k) = f_\sigma(k)$$

If $\sigma(n) = n$ then $f_\sigma(n - 1)$ corresponds to a permuted sum of length $n - 1$ so we can use the induction hypothesis to show
$$f_\sigma(n) = f_\sigma(n - 1) + x_n = f(n - 1) + x_n = f(n)$$

If $\sigma(n) \ne n$, the idea is to swap the position of the $x_n$ term that's somewhere in the partial sum $f_\sigma(n - 1)$ with $x_{\sigma(n)}$, resulting in $f_\sigma(n) = f_{\sigma'}(n) = f(n)$ for some $\sigma'$ such that $\sigma'(n) = n$. So it suffices to show that the result is true for transpositions, ie, permutations that just swap two elements, because $\sigma' = \tau \circ \sigma$ for some transposition $\tau$, so we can let the initial sequence be $x_{\sigma(n)}$ and get $f_\sigma(n) = f_{\tau\sigma}(n) = f_{\sigma'}(n)$.

I'll leave the rest out for now, including the actual use of commutativity, but that's the idea. If you can prove that permuted sums are equal when the permutation is a transposition then the rest should follow.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have two quick follow-up questions if that's OK. (1) The first is around the definition of $f_\sigma$ and why or how it is well-defined (this was the issue I was trying to convince myself of in the OP). Given an $n$, we are further given a $\sigma: \{0,...,n\} \to \{0,...,n\}$ and, given both of those, you can then seemingly define $f_\sigma$. But I'm hoping you can clarify via Prop 5.11 exactly why this $f_\sigma$ exists.

Comment: For instance, I can convince myself of why $f$ exists by Prop 5.11, because I can define (given the fixed sequence $x$) the sequence of functions $V_n: X^n \to X, \, (y_0,...,y_{n-1}) \mapsto y_{n-1} + x_n$. With this sequence and $a = x_0$ fixed, $f$ is now well-defined. But I can't see how we would do this so as to define $f_\sigma $ likewise by this recursion theorem. For fixed $n$, would you fix the sequence as $V^\sigma_m: X^m \to X, \, (y_0,...,y_{m-1}) \mapsto y_{m-1} + x_{\sigma(m)}$ for all $m \leq n$, and then make an arbitrary assignment for $m > n$ since we don't care about those?

Comment: (2) I just want to understand your argument at the end better. Are you saying that if I can show that permuted sums are equal when the permutation is a transposition, then I will have reduced the arbitrary permutation case to the $\sigma(n) = n$ case you noted first?

Comment: With respect to my question (1) here, that is sort of what I was trying to get at with my "interpret the notation" in the OP. I'm just hoping to fully clarify said interpretation in the context of the recursion theorem (Prop 5.11).

Comment: Given some $\sigma$ we can extend to a sequence in $\Bbb N$ by acting on everything above $n$ as the identity and compose with $x$ to get a new sequence which we can use with Prop 5.11.

Comment: and yes to your second question

Comment: Sorry for being uber pedantic and slow here, I just want to confirm I "get it". At any rate, you are saying that given some $\sigma$ we can extend it to a sequence $s : \mathbb{N} \to X$ where (as for any extension) the restriction of $s$ to the first $n+1$ naturals is $\sigma$ (I have not seen sequences yet in my text which is why I ask). Then, for $f_\sigma$ one has the induced (from the $V_m$ of $f$) sequence $V_m: (y_0,...,y_{m-1}) + x_{s(m)}$ and that is, in turn, enough to define $f_\sigma$ (given the choice $f_\sigma(0 = x_{\sigma(0)$) per Prop 5.11?

Comment: I'm not sure how to view this as composition with $x$, hence why I ask.