# In Peano arithmetic, can we define inequality using successor?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

In Peano arithmetic (first order), we first define natural numbers using a successor function and Peano axioms, then we define addition (and multiplication), and then, we define inequality, as:

$a\leq b\leftrightarrow\exists c\left(a+c=b\right)$

Is there any way to define inequality first, directly from the successor function and Peano axioms? (I mean, if I don't need addition for my purpose, why define it?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a precise sense, the answer is **no**. Namely, let $PA_{succ}$ be the set of PA-theorems in the language containing only the symbol for the successor function; then we can show:

> There are models of $PA_{succ}$ with no definable linear ordering.

In particular, this means that **there is no first-order formula using only successor which PA proves defines a linear ordering**.

Specifically, consider the structure (in the language of successor only) $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$. This is a model of $PA_{succ}$ *(this takes a bit of work, but isn't hard)*, but has no definable linear ordering: consider any automorphism swapping the two $\mathbb{Z}$-parts.

(A bit more thought also shows that there is no formula in the language of successor alone which defines a linear ordering in the standard model $\mathbb{N}$; the key ingredient is the proof that $PA_{succ}$ is *complete*. And in fact thinking along these lines ultimately shows that *no* model of $PA_{succ}$ has a definable linear ordering.)

Comment: For the asker's benefit, I'll note that this answer addresses the technical notion of first-order definability; "$\le$" is not first-order definable over PA[succ], just as neither are $+$ or $·$. However, if the asker wants a 'recursive definition' of "$\le$" in a way that allows one to recover the usual properties of the ordering based on the other axioms of PA[succ], then my answer or Bram28's answer provide possible ways.

Comment: @user21820 Note that I explicitly mentioned first-order logic in my answer.

Comment: Yup; it's just to eliminate the usual confusion that a lot of people have due to having been told that one can recursively define $+$ and $·$ over PA[succ]. It could be due to a misinterpretation of the phrase "recursive definition".

Comment: @user21820 That's a good point.

Comment: I upvoted anyway, and I realize that the asker may have been confused and thought the definition of "$\le$" over the usual PA is like the 'definition' of $+,·$ over PA[succ], which it certainly is not.

Comment: @user21820 They are careful to specify that they mean first-order PA - I think they're just being a bit cavalier about its presentation.

Comment: Well Aris said "then we **define** addition (and multiplication), and then, we **define** inequality", but the first "define" is **different** from the second in precisely the senses we are talking about. So I think it's good for Aris to see both our answers, and our comments. =)

Comment: @user21820 Sure - that's what I meant by "cavalier." :)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I understand that addition is not definable in a language with signature $\left\langle 0,S\right\rangle$ , where $S$ is the successor function. With the recursive definition, we add to the language a non logical symbol, “$+$”, and then we get a signature $\left\langle 0,S,+\right\rangle$ . That is because, there isn't any expression containing only logical symbols, which is equivalent with an expression of the form “$x+y=z$”. From Noah Schweber's answer, I understand that “$\leq$” is not definable either.

Comment: I don't fully understand the example, though. @NoahSchweber, I don't know a lot about model theory yet, so I would appreciate if you add an explanation of what you mean by the structure $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$. Also, what if $\forall x\left(x\in\mathbb{N}\right)$? Is there again a model with no definable linear ordering? Or, if “$x\leq y$” holds only for $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$, is “$\leq$” definable then?

Comment: @user21820, do you mean I should use the term “definition”, only when a new symbol is introduced merely as an abbreviation of an existing expression?

Comment: @ArisMakrides "what if $\forall x(x\in\mathbb{N})$? Is there again a model with no definable linear ordering?" The linear order on $\mathbb{N}$ isn't definable in $(\mathbb{N}; S)$ (note that we don't need to include $0$ since it's definable from $S$ alone). In fact it's even worse: **no** model of $PA_{succ}$ has a definable linear ordering.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: So, the set $\mathbb{N}$ is linearly ordered in one sense, but we can not define an ordering relation? I mean, that is what Peano axioms do, right? They define a series $a,b,c,...$ of objects, in witch one comes after the other. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @ArisMakrides The usual ordering $\le$ is not first-order definable in the structure $(\mathbb{N};S)$. It *is* definable in the structure $(\mathbb{N}; S,+)$, but that's a different structure; similarly it *is* definable in $(\mathbb{N}; S)$ by a second-order formula, but that's a different logic. There are different kinds of definitions out there - that's sort of the point of logic - and in the context of first-order logic, the ordering on the naturals is not definable from the successor operation alone.

Comment: @ArisMakrides: Indeed in logic it is conventional to use "define" only for [definitorial expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864310/21820) where you add a symbol to abbreviate an expression over the original system. Outside logic, you may commonly see people use the phrase "recursive definition", because they are working in a foundational system that supports recursion, where you can define a sequence by specifying a recursive relation between each term and the preceding terms.

Answer (score 2):

One way to axiomatize "$\le$" (better not to call it "defining $\le$") that plays very nicely with induction is:

> $a≤b ⇔ a=0 ∨ ∃c,d ( c≤d ∧ S(c) = a ∧ S(d) = b )$.

Do not forget that, whether you have addition or not, you must be able to prove that $≤$ is a strict total order. That is what truly matters.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: This is obviously not a definition in the usual sense, and you know that I know it. I took it as granted that the asker meant it in the sense of axiomatizing "$\le$".

Comment: Fair, I suppose I was being uncharitable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I'll edit anyway to clarify the terminology just in case someone else gets confused (I admit your concern has some validity).

Comment: I've added an answer explaining my concern, and how that can lead to a *negative* answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have the typical axioms for Successor:

$$\forall x \ s(x) \neq 0$$

$$\forall x \forall y \ (s(x) = s(y) \to x = y)$$

and the Axiom Scheme of Induction, which states that for any formula $\varphi(x)$, we have:

$$(\varphi(0) \land \forall x (\varphi(x) \to \varphi(s(x))) \to \forall x \ \varphi(x)$$

Then, if you add:

$$\forall x \forall y (x < y \leftrightarrow (s(x) = y \lor \exists z (y = s(z) \land x < z))) \tag{*}$$

you can prove all of the following:

$$\forall x \ x < s(x)$$

$$\forall x \ \neg x < 0$$

$$\forall x \neg \exists y  (x < y \land y < s(x))$$

$$\forall x \ \neg x < x \text{  (irreflexivity)}$$

$$\forall x \forall y (s(x) < s(y) \to x < y)$$

$$\forall x \forall y \forall z ((x < y \land y < z) \to x < z) \text{  (transitivity)}$$

$$\forall x \forall y  (x < y \to \neg y < x) \text{  (asymmetry)}$$

$$\forall x \forall y  (x = y \lor x < y \lor y < x) \text{  (trichotomy)}$$

So, you can prove all kinds of important and elementary facts about $<$ by adding that one statement to the basic axioms about $s$.

Of course, you would define $x \leq y$ simply as $x < y \lor x = y$ to get results regarding $\leq$, including:

$$\forall x \ x \leq x \text{  (reflexivity)}$$

$$\forall x \forall y \forall z ((x \leq y \land y \leq z) \to x \leq z) \text{  (transitivity)}$$

$$\forall x \forall y  (x \leq y \lor y \leq x) \text{  (totality)}$$

Also, once you do add the typical axioms for addition:

$$\forall x \ x+0=x$$

$$\forall x \forall y \ x + s(y) = s(x+y)$$

then you can derive the 'standard' definition of inequality in terms of addition:

$$\forall x \forall y (x \leq y \leftrightarrow \exists z \ x + z = y)$$

In sum: Yes, we can have an alternative definition of smaller than or inequality that allow you to prove important things about it without using the axioms of addition.

Comment: Nice and detailed. I didn't check, but I trust you did so I upvoted. =)

Comment: @user21820 Thanks, and yes, I have the fully checked proofs :)

Comment: Wouldn't ∀x∀y(x<y↔s(x)=y∨s(x)<y) work as well? If not, why?

Comment: @ByteEater That wouldn’t work. Note that your statement would be true if we interpret $<$ as a total relationship, i.e. if $x<y$ for *any* $x$ and $y$ … meaning that it doesn’t capture much of interest at all … certainly not many of the things we want to be true of $<$

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like$$a\le b\iff Sb\not\leq a\land Sa=b\lor Sa\le b.$$